# How to open a local excel file in a Xamarin iOS app using TMS FlexCel Studio

Tags: c#, ios, excel, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a local excel document that I need to be able to open in a iOS app i'm making. I also need to be able to add entries to the excel file from the mobile app.  I'm using Xamarin and the TMS FlexCel Studio component is the best option to do this. I have a project set up and have the excel file project added to the project as well as adding the TMS FlexCel Studio component to my project. but I don't know how to load the excel project this is the current code I have:

```
using FlexCel.Core;
using FlexCel.XlsAdapter;
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.IO;
using UIKit;

namespace Justice_Compliance_Monitoring_App
{
    partial class SurveyView : UIViewController
    {

        public SurveyView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {

            XlsFile xls = new XlsFile(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "servey.xlsx"));

            xls.ActiveSheetByName = "Sheet1";  //we'll read sheet1. We could loop over th existing sheets by using xls.SheetCount and xls.ActiveSheet 
            for (int row = 1; row <= xls.RowCount; row++)
            {
                for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= xls.ColCountInRow(row); colIndex++) //Don't use xls.ColCount as it is slow: See Performance.Pdf
                {
                    int XF = -1;
                    object cell = xls.GetCellValueIndexed(row, colIndex, ref XF);

                    TCellAddress addr = new TCellAddress(row, xls.ColFromIndex(row, colIndex));
                    Console.Write("Cell " + addr.CellRef + " has ");
                    if (cell is TRichString) Console.WriteLine("a rich string.");
                    else if (cell is string) Console.WriteLine("a string.");
                    else if (cell is Double) Console.WriteLine("a number.");
                    else if (cell is bool) Console.WriteLine("a bool.");
                    else if (cell is TFlxFormulaErrorValue) Console.WriteLine("an error.");
                    else if (cell is TFormula) Console.WriteLine("a formula.");
                    else Console.WriteLine("Error: Unknown cell type");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The app launches on the emulator but crashes on startup what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You do not want to place that code in the static Main unless you are creating a .Net cmd line program and not a Xamarin.iOS-based one and you removed the call to `UIApplication.Main` so the application is always going to terminate. This type of activity should be done once the application has been initialized, like in your `UIViewController`-based object (i.e. inside your `ViewDidLoad` method). Maybe start with http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/ so you understand the basics first

Comment: SushiHangover thanks for the reply I now have it in a Class instead of the main.cs file however I get this error when I run it on the emulator heres the error i get: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/Users/debroc1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76FB8159-64C5-4BF2-AB9C-9F98E24ACAE6/data/Containers/Data/Application/59F0C6D4-3F22-41A1-B790-407F06543378/Documents/servey.xlsx".

Comment: also I added the updated code to the question just a FYI

Comment: The error is fairly clear, the `.xlsx` is not being found in the location that you are telling it load it from.... i.e. it does exist in `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`

Comment: I understand that its on the root of the project how do I change the Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments to reflect the root of the project? thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Keep it simple to get things working, place your `servey.xlsx` in the `Resource` folder of the project (or in the root of the project) and flag it as `BundleResource`, do not place it in any other sub-directories, and and now you should be able to access it via `XlsFile xls = new XlsFile("survey.xlsx")`. I highly recommend reading up on Xamarin iOS and filesystem access  @ http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/